# Locating Bazel output files?

Tags: bazel

When I run `bazel build`, bazel reports the target's output file.  How can I programmatically query this?

In this example, I want to get the `bazel-out/...` path.

```
$ bazel build foo/bar:registration
INFO: Analyzed target //foo/bar:registration (546 packages loaded, 13485 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //foo/bar:registration up-to-date:
  bazel-out/k8-fastbuild-ST-a82eca4c6b7c/bin/foo/bar/registration/registration_/registration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with great flexibility by using the `cquery` command's [Starlark output mode](https://bazel.build/docs/cquery#output-format-definition). For instance, to obtain output similar to that emitted by `build`, use:

```
 $ bazel cquery --output starlark --starlark:expr '"\n".join([f.path for f in target.files.to_list()])' //foo/bar
```

[In the future](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/15552), there may also be a dedicated option in `cquery` that handles the simple cases without the need to involve Starlark on the command line.

Comment: Confirming this works.  There seems to be a bazel feature request for a --quiet option which will be very good combined with this method.

Comment: Note the loading progress is sent to stderr. So if you pipe the command, only the query output will go into the pipe.